# Does anyone have a copy of the paper describing the HiSeC™ algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-design, reference-request

I'm trying to create a remote controller compatible with HiSec algorithm. It's so old that “National Semiconductor” (now “Texas Instruments”) discontinued NM95HS01/02 and docs are unavailable.

Does anyone have the documentation that describe the algorithm code block if the HiSeC™ –High Security Rolling Code Generator? Maybe someone used them in an old project (at least 10 years ago) and already has the docs to implement the algorithm in a microcontroller.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/sites/default/files/ees/files/NI/pdfs/01/23/DS012302.pdf) from Google - it doesn't look like it has a full spec, but it might be a good jumping-off point.

Comment: Too bad no one at TI answered [your request there](https://e2e.ti.com/support/general/f/266/t/275352) up until today…